# fabric js itext for rtl (Urdu / Arabic)

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs, right-to-left

I want to use RTL languages (Urdu / Arabic) in `IText/Textbox`. When using Urdu text within a `textBox`, the text won't align properly. The letters are placed in wrong places. And whenever you make selection of text it appears in wrong place.

**Text Align Justify:**

[image]

**Text Align Right:**

[image]

Is this because of font or something else ?
any recommendations on this issue?

PS: [my font for RTL](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#nastaliq-aran)

Comment: Can you add your code?